# Extract value from uncorrectly parsed dict from json output

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, flask

I am processing kafka streams in a python flask server. I read the responses with json and need to extract the udid values from the stream. I read each response with request.json and save it in a dictionary. When i try to parse it fails. the dict contains the following values

```
dict_items([('data', {'SDKVersion': '7.1.2', 'appVersion': '6.5.5', 'dateTime': '2019-08-05 15:01:28+0200', 'device': 'iPhone', 'id': '3971',....})])
```

parsing the dict the normal way doesnt work ie event_data['status'] gives error.Perhaps it is because its not a pure dict....?

```
@app.route('/data/idApp/5710/event/start', methods=['POST'])
def give_greeting():
    print("Hola")
    event_data = request.json
    print(event_data.items())
    print(event_data['status'])
    #print(event_data['udid'])
    #print(event_data['Additional'])
    return 'Hello, {0}!'.format(event_data)
```

The values contained in event data are the following

```
dict_items([('data', {'SDKVersion': '7.1.2', 'appVersion': '6.5.5', 'dateTime': '2019-08-05 15:01:28+0200', 'device': 'iPhone', 'id': '3971',....})])
```

The expected result would be this result

```
print(event_data['status'])->start
print(event_data['udid'])->BAEB347B-9110-4CC8-BF99-FA4039C4599B
print(event_data['SDKVersion'])->7.1.2
etc
```

the output of 
print(event_data.keys()) is dict_keys(['data'])

Comment: what's the output of ``print(event_data.keys())``? (Please add it to the question, do not post it as a comment)

Comment: There's no problem with the parsing, you're making assumptions about the structure of the data that your print output doesn't support.

Comment: And so to extract the udid,status etc from the dict shown, what could be a possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are expecting is wrapped in an additional `data` property.
You only need to do one extra step to access this data.

```
data_dict = request.json
event_data = data_dict['data']
```

Now you should be able to access the information you want with

```
event_data['SDKVersion']
...
```

as you have described above.

As @jonrsharpe stated, this is not an issue with the parsing. The parsing either fails or succeeds, but you will never get a "broken" object (be it dict, list, ...) from parsing JSON.